# How we can convert an string of array to Array in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

Example :

Input = '[1,2,3]' // typeof string

Expected Output = [1,2,3] //typeof Array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use JSON.parse to parse an string into an array/object

```js
let myArray = JSON.parse(input)
```

Comment: You should not do the work of user users